# why Laravel Models is giving null, while query builder is returning a value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Model Campaign all other model with laravel model structure working fine but on this model its giving null i dont know the reason i wnated to know the reason.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Auth;

class Campaign extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'campaigns';
    public $timestamps = true;


    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'campaign_type_id',
        'medium_type_id ',
        'pause ',
        'uuid',
        'resend_to_days',
        'trigger_mailing',
        'send_to_all',
        'email_id',
        'created_by'
    ];
}
```

Controller values:

```
// returns null
$campaign = Campaign::where('uuid',  $campaign_uuid)->first();
// returns value
$campaign = DB::table('campaigns')->where('uuid', '=', $campaign_uuid)->first();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Check the queries they both are running, and you will find out the issue.

Comment: Is uuid the primary key of the model?

Comment: @fecnert the first line of code giving value null, the second line of code giving me the result i wanted. No i want to know why the 1st line of code is not working im new to laravel it should work

Comment: @btl yes! it is primary key

Comment: have added $table , $primaryKey in your CampaignModel ?

Comment: Have you set the primary key property on the model to reflect that?

Comment: can you please add code of your model, or check query log using `DB::getQueryLog();`

Comment: @jigarShah added

Comment: specify primary key and check difference between query log of both queries

Comment: id is primary key